# SQl Question :Select the text after 7th and before 8th underscore from the below text

Tags: mysql, sql

Select the text after 7th and before 8th underscore from the below text.

A_B_C_D_Dhiren_H_I_J_K

A_B_C_D_jairam_H_I_J_K

A_B_C_D_kumar_H_I_J_K

Answer (score 1):

One method is `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, '_', 8), '_', -1)
```

You can also use the "occurence" argument with `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^_]+', 1, 7)
```